# Can I determine if user denied access to photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

In iOS, is there a way to check if the user has not allowed access to the photos on app launch?  I am working on an app that uses the photo albums heavily, really as a requirement or nearly so, and would like to be able to have a contingency if they decide not to allow access.

Comment: @JitendraDeore Huh, what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try [`[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ALAssetsLibrary/authorizationStatus)

Make sure to include the "AssetsLibrary" framework in your project and add `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` to your file.

Comment: I don't want to upvote this for fear of ruining your 1337 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift equivalent.

`import AssetsLibrary`

After importing, calling `ALAssetsLibrary.authorizationStatus()` returns either

`NotDetermined`

`Restricted`

`Denied`

`Authorized`

from the `ALAuthorizationStatus` enum.